# "Fundamental Cube" for 3-Manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am trying to visualize the simplest 3-manifolds: $T^3$, $S^3$, $S^2 \times S^1$, $\mathbb{R}P^3$, $S^2 \times I$, and so on.

I am used to thinking about $T^2$, $S^1 \times I$, $S^2$, and $\mathbb{R}P^2$ in terms of the fundamental square. $T^2$ is the square with opposite edges identified, $S^1 \times I$ is gotten by chopping the square in half and leaving the boundary, $S^2$ is gotten from $S^1 \times I$ by shrinking the boundary to a point, and $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is gotten by chopping $S^2$ in half and identifying opposite edges of the new boundary.

Can someone describe an analogous procedure to me for 3-manifolds whose fundamental domain is the cube?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you'll need to be more specific in your question. Is it about "visualization?" or a formal, combinatorial "procedure" that gives a space which is technically either of the spaces you described.

One could say, $T^3$ is the space resulting from identifications of certain faces and vertices of the cube $I\times I \times I$, after an appropriate labelling of them. Will it enhance your ability to visualize them? I don't know.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "same procedure". The number of 3-manifolds built out of a single cube by identifying its faces is extremely small. Are you looking for a complete list?

Comment: to widen the scope of your visualizations visit  https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/cucei-maths/elementary-3-manifolds/  for some extra considerations